# Cartesian-closed categories of algebras

Tags: monads, cartesian-closed-categories, ct.category-theory

If the Kleisli-category of a monad is Cartesian-closed, can we say when the category of Eilenberg-Moore algebras is?

Comment: David, could you provide your motivations for this question? 

Personally, I find it easier to rummage up examples where the Eilenberg-Moore category of algebras (over a cartesian closed category) is cartesian closed, than I do for where the Kleisli category is cartesian closed. If you could provide examples of what you have in mind, that could be helpful. 


Comment: If you're still interested in this, you might also be interested in this paper by Fiore and Menni: http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/15/2/15-02abs.html